# Convert callback/event-based C API to "non-callback" API

Tags: c, callback

I'm trying to build a bi-directional conversion between a binary format and JSON in **C** (to make the mapping scriptable). I looked at 13 C JSON parsers, and only found 2 that had all the features I wanted. One is LGPL, and the other one uses callbacks. Having to put my code into a separate DLL, so I don't mix LGPL with proprietary code, is a complicated, so I would try the "callback API" first.

The callback-based API looks about like this (heavily edited code):

```
typedef void *(*api_malloc_func)(void *ctx, size_t sz);
/* ... */
typedef struct {
    api_malloc_func malloc;
    /* ... */
} api_config_params;

typedef struct {
    int (* api_on_bool)(void * ctx, int boolVal);
    int (* api_on_int)(void * ctx, long long intVal);
    /* ...*/
    /* "user-defined data", passed to callbacks. */
    void * ctx;
} api_callbacks;

api_handle api_config(const api_callbacks * callbacks, const api_config_params * cfg);

api_status api_parse(api_handle hand, const unsigned char * json, size_t len);
```

But what I want/need, to make this API "look like" the binary API, is something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    api_malloc_func malloc;
    /* ... */
    /* "user-defined data" */
    void * ctx;
} api_config_params;

api_handle api_config(const api_config_params * cfg);

typedef enum api_type_t {
    api_type_bool,
    api_type_int,
    /* ... */
} api_type_t;

api_type_t api_peek_type(api_config_params* reader);

bool api_read_bool(api_config_params* reader, bool* boolVal);

bool api_read_int(api_config_params* reader, long long* intVal);

/* ... */
```

It's been **forever** since I last coded in C/C++ (I'm a "Java Programmer" now), so I can't figure out how I can wrap the callback/event-based API, to make it "non-callback/event-based" aka "synchronous".

So, how would I do that? Ideally, without making the code non-thread-safe. Is that even possible?

NOTE: I guess I could make the binary API use callbacks instead, but that would make it slower, and I only care about the speed of the binary API, not the speed of the JSON API.

Comment: You would either need to build the entire data structure into memory and your API would navigate that data (in which you'd probably be better off with an existing query language like XPath instead of invention your own as you did), or you would need to run the parser in a separate thread or coro.

Comment: @ikegami I've chosen those 2 JSON APIs *specifically* because they allowed "streaming". I would have had plenty of alternatives, if I wanted to use DOM-style parsing/generating, but be limited by the available memory.

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between a callback-style parsing API and a direct-call parsing API such as you outline: the former analyzes its input and *tells you* what it found, whereas the latter requires you to decide in advance what you expect to find, and request that (and raise an error if that doesn't work).  These are not easily reconcilable.

Comment: FWIW, a callback-based API is pretty much what I would expect for a streaming-style parser.  If it is important to have matching styles, then you would probably have an easier time wrapping a callback API around the direct call API for the binary format than the other way around.

Comment: Side note: isolating LGPL functionality in its own DLL is not automatically sufficient to avoid your application being a derivative.  Such isolation helps make that case, but the analysis is more complex than that.

Comment: @Sebastien Diot, Re "*I've chosen those 2 JSON APIs specifically because they allowed "streaming"*", ok, but that doesn't change what I said. You're bound by one of those two approaches, and you just eliminated one.

Comment: @John Bollinger, Streaming is equally possible both push parsers (i.e. one that uses a callback) and pull parsers (i.e. one where you request the next thing). I'm not sure why you expect one over the other. I mean, file handles are the most common example of streams, and they are commonly access through pull interfaces (`read`, `fgets`, `scanf`, etc). libxml, as another example, provides a pull parser.

Comment: @ikegami,   File handles and streams are not directly relevant because they do no parsing.  I suppose that what I expect of parsers is substantially driven by my personal experience, but that's a side issue.  Regardless of my or anyone else's expectations of parser design in general, I maintain that it would almost certainly be easier to implement a push interface on top of a pull interface than the other way around, given the objective of avoiding construction of an in-memory model of the input.

Comment: @John Bollinger, Re "*it would almost certainly be easier to implement a push interface on top of a pull interface*", Without a doubt! It would look something like `while ( it = get_next() ) push( it );`.

Comment: An unmentioned possibility: Write your own parser. JSON is quite a simple language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, how would I do that? Ideally, without making the code non-thread-safe. Is that even possible?

With a callback-based parser, there is little room to layer a pull-based interface directly on top.  The control flow is committed to reading the input and dispatching events.  Execution of a callback can take arbitrarily long and perform arbitrary work, but you can't run a pull interface there because the parser doesn't get to the next item until the callback returns.

You can, however, run a pull-based API in a second thread.  Make the callback functions executed by the low-level push parser enqueue events for the other thread to consume.  If necessary, use a blocking queue with a fixed capacity, so that the low-level parser cannot get more than a fixed number of events ahead of the high-level pull parser.  The needed synchronization will impose some overhead, but it's unclear how significant that would be for you.  There is no particular reason why that could not be made thread safe, but that involves more considerations than just the interactions already described.